# CROSS-OBJECT UPDATE

Tags: trigger, cross-object

So, this trigger is designed to pull the role name from User obj (which is a lookup to Role) and update the account field on the Contact obj (which is a lookup to Accounts). Im currently getting error on line 8 `(con.Account.name = User.UserRole.name;)`, `"Illegal assignment from Schema SObjfield to String"`. Did I jack this up completely by using Map instead of 2 Lists, or is it just a technicality? Please help soonest? My first Trigger!

```
trigger updateFieldwithMissionName on Contact (after insert, before update){ 
    Map <Id, Account> Users = new Map <Id, Account>();
    for (Contact Con : Trigger.new){
            Users.put(Con.account.name, null);
         for (Account Usr : [select Id, name from Account where Id in :Users.keyset()]){
            Users.put (Usr.Id, Usr);
             if(Usr != null || con.Account.name!= Account.name){
                 con.Account.name = User.UserRole.name;
                 update con;
             }  
        }       
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thom, the account field (which, as you pointed out, is a lookup to account) can never have the ID (or name) of a UserRole. Can you edit your question to elaborate on what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the Account name like that, You need to set it by ID

This line should be changed to set the ID not the name

```
con.Account.name = User.UserRole.name;
```

Also there seem to be some logic issue on the way you write the trigger. Double check that.

Comment: Changed the logic some..





 
    Map <String, String> Users = new Map <String, String>();
    for (Contact Con : Trigger.new){
            Users.put('a.name','User.userrole.name');
         for (Account a: [select Id, name from Account where Name = :'user.userrole.name']){
            Users.put ('user.userrole.name', 'a.name');
            for(User usr:[select Id, name,user.userrole.name from User]){
                 if(Usr!= null ||'con.Account.Name' != 'user.userrole.name'){
                 update(con);
                  
                 }
            }  
        }       
    }       
}